# Convert javascript variable to ColdFusion variable without ajax

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have a js variable that I need to pass in as a variable in an URL, however that variable should be passed as a ColdFusion variable. I know ToScript that converts cf variable to js variable. Is there any function or any way to do it viceversa without ajax?

```
<script>
  function show(obj){
   if (obj.value == "Store")
    {
       var strID = "1";
    }
 }

</script>
ColFusion Code: I need to pass CF variable in EvalID=#CFVar#
<button type="button" onClick="location.href='admin.cfm?EvalID=1';">
```

Comment: You can use innerHTML() to change the content of a webpage.

Comment: Do you mean to do something like this?   $(#someid).append()

Comment: maybe i'm not understanding this right, but if you got a js variable and you want to pass it to a coldfusion page in a url, couldn't you just do something like window.location.href = 'admin.cfm?var=' + jsValue; and then in coldfusion use url.var?